# install nginx ingress on AKS 1.21.7

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, nginx-ingress

Recently, I upgraded my Azure Kubernetes Cluster from `1.19.11` to `1.21.7`.
Subsequently, I am upgrading nginx ingress on the cluster

```
[]$ helm list -A | grep nginx-ingress
nginx-ingress   ingress-basic   1               2021-01-18 13:07:23.842072063 +0000 UTC deployed        ingress-nginx-3.15.2            0.41.2


$ kubectl exec -it nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller-85b8676f7d-8qjw5 -n ingress-basic sh
kubectl exec [POD] [COMMAND] is DEPRECATED and will be removed in a future version. Use kubectl exec [POD] -- [COMMAND] instead.
/etc/nginx $ nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.19.4
/etc/nginx $
```

I want to upgrade nginx to `1.20.0 plus` version. Do we need to specify the version in command below?

```
helm upgrade --install ingress-basic ingress-nginx \
  --repo https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx \
  --namespace nginx-ingress --create-namespace
```

```
 kubectl describe pod nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller-65b69d4895-d4cft -n ingress-basic | grep Image:
    Image:        demoacr.azurecr.io/nginx-ingress-controller:nginx-0.35.0-rancher2
```

Comment: @anarxz Thanks for your response , my issue not yet resolved

Answer (score 0):

To upgrade your ingress-nginx installation to a specific version, you can set the flag `--version`, as specified in [Helm docs](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_upgrade/):

```
helm upgrade [RELEASE] [CHART] [flags]
```

```golang
--version string specify a version constraint for the chart version to use. 
This constraint can be a specific tag (e.g. 1.1.1) or it may reference a valid range (e.g. ^2.0.0). 
If this is not specified, the latest version is used
```

The command should look like this:

```yaml
helm upgrade --install ingress-basic ingress-nginx \
  --repo https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx \
  --namespace nginx-ingress --create-namespace \
  --version 1.20.0
```

It is worth mentioning, that you can also upgrade your nginx installation without Helm by changing the version of the image in your controller Deployment - just change the image  tag to the version you wish to upgrade to - `v1.20.0` . More details about it in [Upgrade NGINX Ingress Controller](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/upgrade/#without-helm).

Comment: When i describe my nginx pod  i find below images is being used"" kubectl describe pod nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller-65b69d4895-d4cft -n ingress-basic | grep Image:
    Image:        demoacr.azurecr.io/nginx-ingress-controller:nginx-0.35.0-rancher2""  if i change the image tag with "nginx-1.1.1-rancher1" will it work

Comment: $ helm upgrade --install ingress-basic ingress-nginx \
>   --repo https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx \
>   --namespace nginx-ingress --create-namespace \
>   --version 1.20.1
Release "ingress-basic" does not exist. Installing it now.
Error: chart "ingress-nginx" version "1.20.1" not found in https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx repository